# How do I get the value of input in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vb.net

I'm passing json values via serializer into this input. How do I retrieve the dynamic values? This returns "[" instead of the json values.

```
<input id="jsonValue" type="hidden" value="<%=sb.ToString%>"/>

 $('#jsonValue').val();
```

An example of the values being passed to this input would be:

```
      {["Blah","BliBlah","Temporary Employee",000001],["Blah","BlihBlah","Mgr",000002]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't your javascript, your html is invalid. you need to make the json string safe for html, replace all occurrences of `"` with `&quot;`. I'm not sure how to do that in vb.net, but it shouldn't be too difficult.

```
<input id="jsonValue" type="hidden" value="["foo"]"/>
```

becomes

```
<input id="jsonValue" type="hidden" value="[&quot;foo&quot;]"/>
```

Many server-side languages have a method that will do this for you.

Comment: .replace("""", "&quot;")

Comment: this possibly? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdek0zbf.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: This almost works! I think it's blowing up if there are spaces though. So it returns, ""["Blah","BliBlah","Temporary"

Comment: for debugging, output the result into a textarea.

Comment: Disclaimer: I consider this evil, but since you're writing it out to the page anyway, did you consider cutting out the middle man and putting the JSON into a javascript variable? I.E. in a script tag do var jsonValue = <%=sb.ToString%>;

Comment: This fixed the original issue. Thanks a lot Kevin!